# jQuery plugin is not rendered after angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am writing a simple tabs application, I used angular js directive to to call the jquery tabs plugin, but the view is not updated properly and I do not see the tabs.

http://jsbin.com/UDIHOTIY/1/edit?html

Here is the code snippet. Can someone help me how to render the tabs correctly?

Comment: You have seen the exception right? Line 4: $scope.tabs=data; --- Mixed spaces and tabs.

Comment: @YagizOzturk this actually should not be a problem in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the DOM is not ready before the directive fires. Using a `$timeout` works for me:

```
.directive('hTabs', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            $timeout(function(){
                var jqueryElm = $(elm[0]);
                $(jqueryElm).tabs();
            },1000);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: setting a timeout in my directive is working. I have one question though, how do I choose the right time out? What is the difference between setting timeout to 0 vs 1000?

Comment: Initially I tried with 0 but did not work. Since you 're not firing any https, a delay of 1 - 2 secs should be good I think.